# Lipschitz continuity of continuously differentiable function

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Is it true that a continuously differentiable function in a Banach space $X$ is locally lipschitz in $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the derivative can be continuous but unbounded. For example, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},f(x)=x^2$ is in fact $C^\infty$ but not globally Lipschitz.

Edit: locally the answer is still no in infinite dimensions, because the derivative is an essentially arbitrary continuous function, and continuous functions on infinite dimensional Banach spaces can be unbounded on balls.

Comment: Sorry, I meant locally. I know that it is true in finite dimensional case.

Comment: @Rabat Well, you need functions which are continuous on all of $X$ to be bounded on whatever you mean by a "neighborhood". This can't be a usual neighborhood in the infinite dimensional setting because infinite dimensional balls are not compact.

Comment: I see now, thanks